# Unable to get a simple OpenGL triangle to rotate

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, jogl, translate

I have a method `drawTriangle` which is referenced in the `display()` method of an OpenGL program in JAVA.

```
public void drawTriangle(GL gl, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3){

    gl.glVertex2d(x1, y1);
    gl.glVertex2d(x2, y2);
    gl.glVertex2d(x3, y3);

}
```

I then call the triangle in `Display()`

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable){
    GL gl = drawable.getGL();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor3f(0.4f, 1.0f, 0.4f);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    drawTriangle(gl,0,0,0,20,100,10);
    gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(90f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glPopMatrix();        
}
```

This then draws a lovely red Triangle.

I can't change the position or rotation of the triangle.

It just spawns it here:

[image: triangle]

Comment: Why are you trying to `glPushMatrix()` after a [`glBegin()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml)?  Where's the corresponding `glEnd()`?

Comment: to be able to pop it later on :)

Comment: Use immediate mode only for pedagogical purposes. I advise you to learn how to use the retained mode (vertex arrays, VBO, VAO, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code.  First of all, `gl.glBegin(...)` should be followed by `gl.glEnd()`. Keep the drawing functions, such as, `drawTriangle(...)` within these two, and any matrix operations outside.

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{ 
    GL gl = drawable.getGL();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor3f(0.4f, 1.0f, 0.4f);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(90f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    drawTriangle(gl,0,0,0,20,100,10); 
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glPopMatrix(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is making a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the transformation after rendering.  This does not work!

- first set up your matrices (i.e. do the transformation)
- then render
- finally popMatrix to restore the original matrix

i.e.:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
    GL gl = drawable.getGL();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(90f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glColor3f(0.4f, 1.0f, 0.4f);
    drawTriangle(gl,0,0,0,20,100,10);
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glPopMatrix();        
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't want to resort to asking something that is probably comparatively simple but it's something i just wasn't seeing in similar posts on here. I will further practice my google-fu

Comment: I can't seem to understand my answer being downvoted other that somebody trying to gain reps.  @GeorgeOthen please mark my answer :)

Comment: I guess because you missed the `glEnd`, anyway I also don't like downvoting without any explanation, +1

Comment: Your original answer still had most of the problems of the original code (missing `glEnd`, matrix stack manipulations inside `glBegin`/`glEnd`), and it was only fixed after somebody else posted a correct answer. It wouldn't seem fair if this answer got accepted, and not the one who first posted the correct code.

Comment: The most important problem was trying to transform after rendering.  Downvoting instead of commenting simply is bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

My example rotates a quad, I assume that you're able to modify it to rotate a triangle:
https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98

It's quoted [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) and in [the JogAmp wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial). Improve your Yacy/DuckDuckGo/IxQuick/Seeks skills next time ;)